# LVS + keepalived for load balancing transparent SQUID proxies

Tags: load-balancing, squid, transparent-proxy, lvs, ipvs

I need to load balance a number of SQUID proxies configured in transparent mode. Below is a simple diagram with one LB and SQUID boxes.

```
               ----------
               | Client |
               ----------
                   | *.1.100
                   |
                   v
net C ====================================== 
            ^ LB VIP=*.1.1      ^
            |                   |
            | *.1.10            | *.1.50
        ----------       ----------------
        |   LB   |       | SQUID tproxy |
        ----------       ----------------
                                | *.6.50
                                |
                                v
net S ======================================
                   ^
                   |
                   | *.6.200
            ---------------
            | HTTP server |
            ---------------
```

The client is able to access the web server when there is no LB by adding static route which uses SQUID tproxy IP as a gateway. When I add LB things break. The LB is configured in DR mode (this is a requirement).
I can not figure out how to configure it so that it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On the Real server you need the VIP IP configured on an interface, preferably loopback.  Also for DR to work they LB and Squids have to be in the same broadcast domain, which from the diagram is not clear but from IPs I am assuming it is the case.

Comment: I did all that. This setup works if SQUID is setup as a forward/reverse proxy. Transparency is probably the problem here. The question is if it is even possible to have load balanced transparent SQUID proxies?

Comment: "The question is if it is even possible to have load balanced transparent SQUID proxies?" - Any luck here?